# change the height of background-color

Tags: css, height, background-color

I'm trying to change the height of background-color in class.

```css
#myclass{
  background-color: #FFF;
  padding: 25px;
  border: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
  height:auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="myclass">
  <div class="col-md-4">image</div>
  <div class="col-md-4">text</div>
  <div class="col-md-4">button</div>
</div>
```

In CSS `height:420px` working but i don't want something like this

Comment: It is really unclear what you want

Comment: So you have an element that is say 500px in height and you want the background to only be on say 400px of that? Is that what you mean? Also you have an id called `myclass`? Thats confusing.. and hopefully you only have one of them as IDs need to be unique.

Comment: i want height:auto. all classes to have background-color white without change height in every media-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're having an issue with floating elements. As the `.col-md-*` elements are floated, your `#myclass` element has no height (thus no background will display). Bootstrap's `.col-md-*` elements are supposed to be wrapped in an element with a `class` of `"row"`, and I believe this will solve your problems:

```
<div id="myclass" class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">...</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">...</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">...</div>
</div>
```

If that isn't an option, you'll need to add an element to clear the floats on those `.col-md-4` elements:

```
<div id="myclass" class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">...</div>
    ...
    <br style="clear: both">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1) If it is a solid background-color - you can add the background as a image

```
#myclass {
background-image:url('pathtoimage/background-image.png');
background-size: 100% 450px;
background-position: left top;
}
```

Solution 2)
Add a fake-background image/color by adding a div inside #myclass.

```
<div id="myclass">
<div class="fake-bg"></div>
<div class="col-md-4">image</div>
<div class="col-md-4">text</div>
<div class="col-md-4">button</div>
</div>
```

Add this to your css:

```
#myclass {
position:relative;
}
.fake-bg {
position:absolute;
left:0;
top:0;
width:100%;
height:450px;
z-index:-1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after {
        content: "";
        display: table;
        line-height: 0;
    }

    .clearfix:after {
        clear: both;
    }
```

please use this css and just put .clearfix with .ror class.
it would work defiantly